# Syntax highlighting not working for Node.js Vash view files in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: html, node.js, visual-studio-2015, vash

In Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 I am building a Node.js application and am using Vash as the view engine. However, when I write HTML in the vash files, the syntax highlighting is not working. It just shows up as plain text. So for example, this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@model.title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>@model.block("body")</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would just show up without any highlight at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Clint Helfers at UPNXT (see [here](https://www.upnxt.com/blog/node-with-express-vash-sqlite)) I was able to get the highlighting working:

In Visual Studio 2015, go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension and then add vash as the extension with the Editor `HTML (Web Forms) Editor`. See below:

[image]

Once I did that, I had to close open .vash files and then, when I reopened them, all of the HTML highlighting worked.